# Create a PL/SQL procedure that calculate total monthly income. Total must be printed by month

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, procedure

Write  a procedure that calculates and displays total income from all sources of all hotels. Totals must be printed by month, and for each month by event and service type. Include discounts.( 10% discount if the reservation date is 2 month before reservation start date).

The tables are:

**Hotel** Table has:

```
Hotel_id, hotel_name, Hotel_city, Hotel_state, Hotel_zip,Hotel_phone
```

**Reservation** Table has:

```
Reservation_id, Hotel_id, Room_num, Service_id, Guest_name, Reservation_date, Reservation_start_date, Reservation_end_date, cancelation_date, Num_of_guest, event_type
```

**Room** Table has:

```
Room_num, Hotel_id, Room_type, Room_capacity, Room_cost
```

**service** table has:

```
service_id, Service_type, Service_cost
```

This is what I tried, but I want to write it in a procedure form; how do I do that? Please help. Thanks

```
select month (Reservation_end_date) as , event_type,
sum(case when days>= 2 then cost- (cost/100)* 10
else cost) as total_cost)



((select distinct reservation.hotel_id,reservation_date, reservation_start_date,
reservation_end_date, event_type, room.room_type as R_type ,room_cost as R_cost,
months_between(reservation_start_date,reservation_date)as months
from reservation, room
where reservation.hotel_id = room.hotel_id;)

union

 (select hotel_name, reservation_date, reservation_start_date,
reservation_end_date, event_type, services_type, services_cost as cost,
months_between(reservation_start_date,reservation_date)as month
from reservation,service, hotel
where reservation.services_id = service.services_id 
and reservation.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id;))

group by month(reservation_end_date),event_type;
```

Comment: There are 4 tables (we don't know what's the relation among them); there's (an invalid & unformatted, difficult to read) query you posted. I suggest you write a query which works *as is*. Then it is a simple task to convert it to PL/SQL - you'll have to select values it returns INTO variables and *do something* with them (display them using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is one option).

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to get the base query right.

To consolidate a set of dates into their common month use `trunc(date_col, 'mm')`. Presumably room costs and service costs should be calculated on a per night basis. 
To calculate the number of nights simply subtract the start date from the end date.

This query should produce the correct result (your stated business rules are incomplete so it's hard to be certain). Like your posted code it has subqueries to calculate the cost of each room reservation and each service reservation. These are aggregated in the outer query:

```
select to_char(r_month, 'YYYY-MON') as rpt_month
       , event_type
       , service_type
       , sum ( (r_cost - r_discount ) * no_of_nights ) as tot_cost
from (      
    select trunc(r.reservation_end_date , 'mm') as r_month
           , r.event_type
           , cast(null as varchar2(10)) as service_type
           , rm.room_cost as r_cost
           , case when months_between (r.reservation_start_date, r.reservation_date) >= 2
              then rm.room_cost * 0.1 
              else 0 end as r_discount 
            , (r.reservation_end_date - r.reservation_start_date ) as no_of_nights
    from  reservation r
          join room rm
              on ( r.room_num = rm.room_num  
              and r.hotel_id = rm.hotel_id )
    union all
    select trunc(r.reservation_end_date , 'mon') as r_month
           , r.event_type
           , sv.service_type
           , sv.service_cost  as r_cost
           , case when months_between (r.reservation_start_date, r.reservation_date) >= 2
              then sv.service_cost * 0.1 
              else 0 end as r_discount 
           , (r.reservation_end_date - r.reservation_start_date ) as no_of_nights
    from  reservation r
          join service sv
              on ( r.service_id = sv.service_id )
    )  
group by r_month
       , event_type
       , service_type
order by r_month
       , event_type
       , service_type      
;
```

The second step is put this into a procedure. Again your requirements are fuzzy: should the procedure take any parameters? what format should the output be in? As the business domain (hotel bookings) and the format of the question (*"write a procedure that ..."*) this appears to be a homework assignment so here is the simplest interpretation of *"display"*. It uses `dbms_output` routines to print to the screen, and `rpad()` and `lpad()` to give a nice layout (obviously the spacings may be wonky, because you haven't provide the datatypes of the various columns) .

```
create or replace procedure display_monthly_reservations as
begin
    << heading >>
    dbms_output.put(rpad('MONTH', 8)); 
    dbms_output.put( rpad('EVENT_TYPE' , 20 ) || ' ');  
    dbms_output.put( rpad('SERVICE_TYPE', 20 ) || ' ');  
    dbms_output.put_line('TOTAL_COST'); 

    << per_line >>
    for r in (
         << insert the query here >> 
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put(r.rpt_month || ' '); 
        dbms_output.put( rpad(r.event_type , 20 ) || ' ');  
        dbms_output.put( rpad(r.service_type , 20 ) || ' ');  
        dbms_output.put_line( lpad(to_char(r.tot_cost , '9999999.99'), 10 ) );   
    end loop per_line;

end display_monthly_reservations;
/
```